# How do I check if a number is a 32-bit integer using Python?

Tags: python, int

In my program I'm looking at a string and I want to know if it represents a 32-bit integer.

Currently I first check if it is a digit at all using `isdigit()`, then I check if it exceeds the value of 2^32  (assuming I don't care about unsigned values).

What's the best way to check that my input string contains a valid 32-bit integer?

Comment: lol...yes it does...but is it a valid way or are there better ways of doing so ?

Comment: Can you post your exact code, so we can see the implementation?

Comment: I would probably use bitwise operators instead.

Answer (score 7):

Found answer here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length

Simplest and most effective solution I think

```
>>> your_num = 2147483651
>>> your_num.bit_length()
32
```

Comment: This function ignores the signed, a bit of checking must be added

Answer (score 4):

Just another idea, see if the value can be packed in a 4 bytes:

```
>>> from struct import pack, error
>>> def test_32bit(n):
...     try:
...             pack("i", n)
...     except error:
...             return False
...     return True
...
```

If working with unsigned values, `pack("I", n)` instead.

Comment: Don't use a bare except clause, as it can catch things such as KeyboardInterrupt that should not be caught here.

Comment: @AbeKarplus I know, but I was just being lazy :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the largest 32-bit integer is [`0xffffffff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647),

Then, we need to check if our number is larger than this value:

```
abs(n) <= 0xffffffff
```

Wrapping an `abs()` around the number will take care of negative cases, too.

Comment: The positive and negative limits are not the same, -2^31 and 2^31-1

Comment: The hex value for a signed integer would be `0x7FFFFFFF`

Answer (score 3):

For unsigned values, this will work:

```
>>> def is32(n):
...     try:
...         bitstring=bin(n)
...     except (TypeError, ValueError):
...         return False
...         
...     if len(bin(n)[2:]) <=32:
...         return True
...     else:
...         return False    
... 
>>> is32(2**32)
False
>>> is32(2**32-1)
True
>>> is32('abc')
False
```

Comment: why can't I just check if it falls within the range of upper and lowerbound values ?

Comment: By using `try` with bin you are validating that n is a valid number. While you are at it, just check if the bits are less than 32 bits long. Works all day long...

Comment: that's pretty cool..but isn't isDigit already checking if it is a valid number?

Comment: i am using the str.isDigit() method as a prescreen to check if it is a number representation at all, then typecasting it into it's integer representation and checking it against it's bounds !!!

Comment: @user1020069: That will probably work too. The way I have written it, Python is doing the math for you. If you are checking a string, it will choke on the valid number of `is32(2**31)` since the string contains '**' It is just more steps. Use what is appropriate for the context.

Comment: @user1020069: You are maybe confusing a string number versus an int as well. Python is typed. '123' is not the same as 123

Comment: does it lose it's precision ?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> def is_int32(number):
...     try:
...         return not(int(number)>>32)
...     except ValueError:
...         return False
```

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers: >>> is_int32(-1): False

Answer (score 3):

We can use left shift operator to apply the check.

```
def check_32_bit(n):
    return n<1<<31
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Potentially more understandable variant: `n<2**31`

Comment: Some explanation for this answer would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution will be like this

```
if abs(number) < 2**31 and number != 2**31 - 1:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

If our number in `[−2^31,  2^31 − 1]` range we are good to go

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> def is_32_bit(n: int) -> bool:
...     if n in range(-2 ** 31, (2**31) - 1):
...         return True
...     return False
... 
>>> is_32_bit(9999999999)
False
>>> is_32_bit(1)
True
```

Comment: This is wrong. Check your ranges. `2**32` should be `(2**31)-1`.