# Reverse digits of an integer in Python

Tags: python

Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer.

**Example 1:**

Input: 123
Output: 321

**Example 2:**

Input: -123
Output: -321

**Example 3:**

Input: 120
Output: 21

Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2^31,  2^31 − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows.

I am trying to solve the reversing int problem, but following solution failed with the following input.

**Input:**
    1534236469

**Output:**
    9646324351

**Expected:**
    0

In my solution, I am checking whether or not given int is bigger than max or min value, and then checking whether or not it is negative.

**My solution**

```
import sys
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if x <sys.maxsize-1  or x > -sys.minsize:

            if str(x)[0] == '-':
                list_mod = list(str(x))
                list_mod.pop(0)
                list_mod.append('-')
                list_mod.reverse()
                join_list = ''.join(list_mod[:])
                return int(join_list)
            else:
                return int(str(x)[::-1])
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: You are testing – and rejecting – too soon. `1534236469` fits into a signed int, but its reverse does not.

Comment: @usr2564301, then how should I handle this situation.

Comment: Can the original fail this test? Then test before (as you are doing). But test after reversing as well. But I am not too sure you are testing correctly, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try converting the int to `string`, then `reverse` and then convert it to `int`.

**Ex:**

```
a = 1534236469
print(int(str(a)[::-1]))
```

**Output:**

```
9646324351
```

To handle the negative number:

```
if str(a).startswith("-"):
    a = a[1:]
    print("-{0}".format(int(str(a)[::-1])))
else:
    print(int(str(a)[::-1]))
```

Comment: Expected value should be `0`. `9646324351` is not int.

Comment: You can use this link to test if int is 32bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928669/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-32-bit-integer-using-python